# Bokeh Python: Laying out multiple plots

Tags: python, dictionary, bokeh

I want to array plots horizontally, use the hplot() function.
My problem is that I generate my plot names dinamically.
Dfdict is a dictionary of dataframes

```
for key in dfdict.keys():
    plot[key] = BoxPlot(dfdict[key], values='oex', ...)
    filename = '{}.html'.format(str(key))
    output_file(filename)
    show(plot[key])
p = hplot(plot.values())
show(p)
```

But i have an error:

ValueError: expected an element of List(Instance(Component)), got seq with invalid items [[, , , , , ]]

Thanks

Comment: Due to the rapid changes in bokeh development it is very important to state for which version of bokeh you are seeking a solution. Please specify.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `hplot` is deprecated in recent releases. You should use `bokeh.layout.row`:

```
from bokeh.layouts import row

# define some plots p1, p2, p3

layout = row(p1, p2, p3)

show(layout)
```

Functions like `row` (and previously `hplot`) take all the things to put in the row as individual arguments.

There is an entire section on layouts in the user's guide:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html

Answer (score 0):

I do it, intead of this

```
p = hplot(plot.values())
```

I am using this

```
p = hplot(*plot.values())
```